# Rmarkdown packages installing

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to install my rmarkdown packages but an error occur; I've tried to search everywhere but I can't solve it. Can you please help me?

```
install.packages("rmarkdown")

There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
              binary source needs_compilation
    rmarkdown    2.3    2.5             FALSE


installing the source package ‘rmarkdown’

provo con l'URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rmarkdown_2.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3203415 bytes (3.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘rmarkdown’ ...
** package ‘rmarkdown’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘rlang’
Calls: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Esecuzione interrotta
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rmarkdown’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rmarkdown’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rmarkdown’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/pt/w_1xy4r906n438hsc3ksgcz40000gn/T/RtmpfUajvL/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: `install.packages("rmarkdown", dependencies = TRUE)` usually works for me, I have also seen some users have to make configs to their user profiles, but try the install first

Answer (score 1):

The error is this:

```
there is no package called ‘rlang’
```

Try installing `rlang` manually with `install.packages("rlang")` and then re-try installing `rmarkdown`.

Alternatively, try to install the binary version instead, with:

```
install.packages("rmarkdown", type = "binary")
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is indicated in the error message

> there is no package called ‘rlang’

Try to install rlang first and then repeat your installation of rmarkdown.